# How to debug the http response headers from a HTTP call

Tags: http, firebug

I've installed FireBug, but I am not sure how to find out if a certain http header is present in my HTTP response. Where should I look for this information?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the Net tab in Firebug to monitor network traffic.  There you can see the complete headers as well as the timing and content of any network/HTTP queries.

Looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Hi Vagrant. Firebug was my first choice too, but I don't seem to have a Net tab. Would you happen to know if this is a Mac OS X feature?

Answer (score 6):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/) is the best tool I know of to do this and much more, including inspecting the entire request/response in many formats including a nice XML browser.

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler in good but sometimes it causes problems because of changing the system proxy configuration.

Check the HTTP Debugger, it's not a proxy and doesn't create such problems
https://www.httpdebugger.com