# Mysql return type at the time of special characters

Tags: php, mysql, utf

Today i get a small problem. Problem is releated to **MySql,UTF**.

I am inserting a french word '**éléphant**' or any other french words  in my database. Database have **utf8_general_ci** Collation type and table collcation also have same.

[image: database_image_for_french_word_elephant]

At the time of getting records.

Receiving data is total different.

```
        [uid] => 1
        [user_name] => ashish
        [lid] => 6
        [list_name] => test
        [Item ID] => 23
        [Item Name] => Ã©lÃ©phant
        [description] => Ã©lÃ©phant
        [image] => 
        [order] => 1
        [created] => 2014-12-26 15:30:58
    )
```

French Word '**éléphant**' change in   **Ã©lÃ©phant** .I am not using any functions related to utf .I am just inserting data as usual.  I want exact same. What i do for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your database encoding looks right.

Now you need to check your PHP running encoding. So, on the PHP page you are reading this data, add this line:

```
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

**EDIT:**

On the page you are reading your data, add these lines:

```
<html>
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-language" content="fr" />
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">
</head>
<body>
<?php
 // your code
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but i already applied <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> in my html file as well as <?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?> in .php

Comment: @railsbox Strange. What if you write directly`echo 'éléphant';` ? is it displayed correctly ?

Comment: @railsbox are you using *firebug* ? check headers response to see its content type response

Comment: yes i am using firebug. Where i can check my content type response ?

Comment: @railsbox check this [picture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374100/how-to-debug-the-http-response-headers-from-a-http-call/5374152#5374152)

Comment: @railsbox Please, follow the detailed steps on the answer I wrote after I edited mine.

Comment: i am getting Content-Type application/json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67711/discussion-between-railsbox-and-begueradj).

Answer (score 0):

Check if in the response header you have : `Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8`

[image]

(I'm using chrome developer tool in the screenshot)

if not, try to add this line of code to your HTML page :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

or this line of code before serving the response in your PHP file :

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but i already applied <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> in my html file as well as <?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?> in .php

Comment: What do you get in the Response header for Content-Type ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in php

> **header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');**