# Perl Facebook Login with Mechanize failed cookies error

Tags: facebook, perl, cookies

I have a script that scrapes my scores from an website. This website uses my Facebook account for logging in. Since a few days the script does not work anymore and I get the following error:

> Cookies Required: 
>   Cookies are not enabled on your browser. Please enable cookies in your
>   browser preferences to continue.

I searched on this forum and I found a similar problem:
I tryed the given solution but it did not work.

I have export my FaceBook login cookies.txt from Google Chrome with this plugin. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookiestxt/njabckikapfpffapmjgojcnbfjonfjfg?hl=en and save the cookies.txt in the same folder as the script:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
use use HTTP::Cookies::Netscape;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( cookie_jar => HTTP::Cookies::Netscape->new( file => $cookies.txt ) );
$mech->agent_alias('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0');
$mech->get("https://www.facebook.com/login.php");
$mech->submit_form(
fields => {
    email => '<my email here>',
    pass => '<my password here>',
   }
);

open($out, ">",  "output_page.html") or die "Can't open output_page.html: $!";
print $out $mech->content;
```

In the script I use Agent: Firefox but the cookies are exported from Chrome, is this maybe an issue? I have tryed different methods and languages Python and perl.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31283839/facebook-login-via-perl-wwwmechanize-login-error-cookies-required

Comment: Yes I have already read that topic, I tryd the solution by exporting the cookies.txt. unfortunately I recieve the same error: Cookies are not enabled on your browser.

Answer (score 2):

> Always `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of your script

In your script This line is problem

`my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( cookie_jar => HTTP::Cookies::Netscape->new( file => $cookies.txt ) );`

Change it to

```
my $cookies= 'cookies.txt'; #your cookies file path here
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( cookie_jar => HTTP::Cookies::Netscape->new( file => $cookies ) );
```

Correcting all errors your script should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTTP::Cookies::Netscape; #you were using two times use
my $cookies='your cookies file path';
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( cookie_jar => HTTP::Cookies::Netscape->new( file => $cookies) );
$mech->agent_alias('Windows Mozilla'); #this is right user agent
$mech->get("https://www.facebook.com/login.php");
$mech->submit_form(
fields => {
    email =>'your username',
    pass => 'your password',
   }
);

open(my $out, ">",  "output_page.html") or die "Can't open output_page.html: $!"; #make lexical variables using my
print $out $mech->content;
```

I will suggest you to read [WWW::Mechanize documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/WWW-Mechanize-1.75/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm)

Note: As many other users suggested this type of login using tools are against their ToS.So please check [Facebook API](http://search.cpan.org/~unobe/WWW-Facebook-API-0.4.18/lib/WWW/Facebook/API.pm).

Comment: do this `my $cookies='/Users/Boy/Downloads/cookies.txt'`

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to send credentials if you load correct cookies because this code works for me (as you can see **you only need two cookies** `c_user` and `xs`):

```
my $config = {

    auth_token =>
      "c_user=100009668980203;xs=143%3AfaO_5XiRk_rWOg%3A2%3A1435225463%3A-1",
};

my @cookies = split /;/, $config->{auth_token};

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

foreach my $cookie (@cookies) {

    my ( $cookie_name, $cookie_value ) = split /=/, $cookie, 2;
    $mech->cookie_jar->set_cookie( 0, $cookie_name, $cookie_value, '/',
        '.facebook.com', undef, 1, 1, undef, 1 );
}

$mech->get("https://www.facebook.com/messages/");

$mech->save_content("$Bin/Messages_test.htm", binmode => ':raw' );
```