# node.js and geoserver CORS

Tags: node.js, express, openlayers, openlayers-3, geoserver

I have node.js server 0.10.12 and express.js 4.8.5. Node.js is the web server, includes openlayers 3.9.0.

Geoserver 2.1.3 serves the WMS layer. Later, I will implement vector layers.

There is only one route (for the index page)

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
```

The `index.js` contains

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'openlayers3 testing', head: 'Welcome' });
  next();
});

module.exports = router;
```

So the `app.js` has

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');//explained above

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

I added the following for CORS

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});


app.get('/', routes);
```

And in the `index.ejs` I set my Geoserver WMS layer like this

```
var ait = new ol.layer.Tile({
extent: textent,
source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/mymap/wms',
  crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
  attributions: [new ol.Attribution({
    html: '&copy; ' +'<a href="http://www.geo.admin.ch/internet/geoportal/' +'en/home.html">' +'National parks / geo.admin.ch</a>'
  })],
   params: {'LAYERS': 'mymap:planet_osm_polygon, mymap:planet_osm_line, mymap:planet_osm_roads, mymap:planet_osm_point'},
   serverType: 'geoserver'
 })
```

})

And I get the error

`Image from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5550' is therefore not allowed access.`

I tried a lot of variations I found online. I put the code before the `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`. I put it inside the `router.get` of the `index.js`. Still nothing. I fail to understand what is wrong.

Thanks

**notes**

This works in internet explorer 11. No errors and I can actually see the layer

No errors in firefox 30 but I cannot see the layer

In chrome 45 I cannot see the layer and I get that error

Comment: Did you see - https://stackoverflow.com/a/25025579/4640499?

Comment: @slevin you are adding CORS on wrong side. You are connecting from node app to your Geoserver. So, CORS should be added in your Geoserver, not on Node app.

Comment: @JonatasWalker Yes, thanks, I plan to re-set my Geoserver according to this

Comment: @ɦassansin Hi there. I come to realise this, you are right. I now read articles on CORS. But, for conversation sake, lets assume that I can only access and set `node.js` and not `Geoserver`. What do I do then? Set a proxy to `node.js`? Thanks

Comment: yes, reverse proxy would be one solution in that case.

Comment: @ɦassansin Hi there again. Setting CORS to Geoserver is not possible due to technical problems. I want to set a peverse proxy on node, but I dont know how to do it. There are many npm modules out there and I dont know witch one fits. Any tips? Thanks again

Comment: you can try https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware

Comment: @JonatasWalker This is a good SO Q&A , but this uses Tomcat and my Geoserver uses and old Jetty. A similar solution is this `http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.geoserver.user/42219` but did not work for me and I dont trust it because I dont know if its official. Thanks anyhow

Comment: @ɦassansin Hey.`http-proxy-middleware` looks amazing and I did not see it, so I will experiment. I now try to create a reverse proxy with it, but I dont actually know what to do. If you dont mind checking this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952476/cannot-set-proxy-on-node-js`. Thanks again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Forget `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'` it is a huge security risk. Set the name of the requesting domain instead and maintain a whitelist of domains.

I think it is obvious that your middleware does not set the headers in the `http://localhost:8080` response. Check the headers on the network panel, firebug, etc... and debug it. [How to debug the http response headers from a HTTP call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374100/how-to-debug-the-http-response-headers-from-a-http-call)

Firefox does not handle CORS errors always properly, so you should check chrome as well. Internet explorer works differently from the others: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22450633/607033 so it accepts `http://localhost:5550` as same origin, that's why your buggy code works in msie. Try to use custom named domains by appending the hosts file, and I am sure you will get error message from msie as well.

**edit - to catch up with the comments**

The main problem with the example code, that the webapp (domain: `http://localhost:5550`) returns your CORS headers. Since the webapp wants to access the geoserver (`http://localhost:8080`) from the browser, the geoserver should grant access and not the webapp. So the geoserver should return the CORS headers instead of the webapp.

According to slevin it is not possible with the version of geoserver they currently use. A possible workaround to add a reverse proxy and serve the geoserver under a subfolder of the webapp or serve the webapp under a subfolder of the geoserver. This way they both would have the same origin. Another option to stick with different domains, but add the CORS headers to the geoserver response using the reverse proxy.

Comment: Chrome console gives a `200` status for the maps from `localhost:8080`, but no size. And the CORS error. Firebug also gives a `200` status , there is a size, but no errors. I dont get what you mean by "I think it is obvious that your middleware does not set the headers in the http://localhost:8080 response. Check the headers on the network panel, firebug, etc... and debug it.". If you want to update your answer and explain to me, that would be great, because frankly I am stack.

Comment: I also red `http://jonathanmh.com/how-to-enable-cors-in-express-js-node-js/` and `http://www.tamas.io/node-jsexpress-cors-implementation/`,  and tryed to implement, but no luck. Thakns

Comment: @slevin According to your error message the access control headers do not show up in the response and that causes the problem. I added a link about how to check the response headers in firefox with firebug, but you can do that with any current browser using the dev tools.

Comment: @slevin In my opinion the problem that you are adding the access control headers to the `localhost:5550` response and not to the `localhost:8080` response. I don't think you fully understand how CORS works. You should read the manual. http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

Comment: Setting CORS on Geoserver (`localhost:8080`) not possible due to technical problems, and all the hacks I saw and tryed to implement failed. If I set a proxy or reverse proxy on Node (`localhost:5550`) will this solve the CORS related problems?

Comment: @slevin If you mean you serve geoserver from 5550 or you serve your webapp from 8080 through a proxy, then both would work. If you could put the geoserver behind a proxy on a 3rd domain, then you would be able to add the allow origin headers as well. You should ask geoserver developers to implement a CORS header feature in the next version.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort, thanks for making me understand the concept. I now try to set a reverse proxy, but I fail to implement it. If you dont mind checking this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952476/cannot-set-proxy-on-node-js` would be great. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Try starting `google-chrome` with disable security and allowing access for local files

```
google-chrome --disable-web-security --allow-file-access-from-files
```

This will disable the same origin policy and allow local files to access each other.

*You might get Stability and security warning, you can avoid that for development.*